# How to use httpd (https/ssl) as proxy server for tomcat

Tags: ssl, httpd, httpd.conf, tomcat8, ajp

I have installed httpd and tomcat on my server but somehow I'm not able to connect them.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.harshrathod.dev
        ServerAlias harshrathod.dev
        ServerAdmin ******************
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.harshrathod.dev [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =harshrathod.dev
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /projects/legend ajp://localhost:8009/legend
ProxyPassReverse /projects/legend ajp://localhost:8009/legend

</VirtualHost>
```

Accessing the legend page on harshrathod.dev shows error instead of responding with the index.jsp page in "../webapps/legend". Both the servers are up and running. HTTPD is listenng on 80 and tomcat on localhost:8080

Do I need to paste this on:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /projects/legend ajp://localhost:8009/legend
ProxyPassReverse /projects/legend ajp://localhost:8009/legend
```

in httpd-le-ssl.conf ?

There are these errors related to proxy on error_log

```
[Sun Mar 29 17:13:28.909192 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 6690] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH00957: AJP: attempt to connect to 120.0.0.1:8009 (120.0.0.1) failed
[Sun Mar 29 17:13:28.909285 2020] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 6690] [client 27.56.193.67:10405] AH00896: failed to make connection to backend: 120.0.0.1, referer: https://harshrathod.dev/
[Sun Mar 29 17:18:19.513513 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 6659] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH00957: AJP: attempt to connect to 120.0.0.1:8009 (120.0.0.1) failed
[Sun Mar 29 17:18:19.513582 2020] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 6659] [client 103.125.234.198:57195] AH00896: failed to make connection to backend: 120.0.0.1, referer: https://harshrathod.dev/
```

Comment: Can you include the error it returns in your question as well as any relevant output from your apache error log?

Comment: The naming of Apache's secondary config files is not canonical (they are all included from the main config), but if `httpd-le-ssl.conf` contains the SSL `<VirtualHost>` you should put the `ProxyPass` and related directives there.

Comment: I have added the errors related to proxy. The connection is failing.

Comment: Check whether Tomcat is running and you have a `<Connector>` element of type AJP/1.3 in `server.xml`.

Comment: Now I have moved:

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /projects/legend ajp://localhost:8009/legend
ProxyPassReverse /projects/legend ajp://localhost:8009/legend

to httpd-el-ssl.conf

Comment: Yes, there is a connector element in server.xml . And it is working fine. I have tested it using "wget". It is responding with index.jsp in "../webapps/legend". But the proxy stuff is not working.

Comment: Thankyou so much, moving worked. Can you post your comment as answer. I will upvote it. Thankyou so much Mr. Karwasz. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<VirtualHost *:80>` is set up to redirect everything to port `443` (at least for the `harshrathod.dev` and `www.harshrathod.dev` domains), so the `ProxyPass` directive will never be executed.

As you suggest in your question, you should move the `ProxyPass` and related directives to your `<VirtualHost *:443>`.

Remark also, that Tomcat's `HTTP/1.1` `<Connector>` on port `8080` is not used in this configuration. You use the `AJP/1.3` `<Connector>` on port `8009` instead, which is a faster protocol. If you would like to use the (slower) `HTTP/1.1` `<Connector>` use:

```
ProxyPass /projects/legend http://localhost:8080/legend
ProxyPassReverse /projects/legend http://localhost:8080/legend
```